# Ubuntu server installer with SSHD

Tags: ubuntu, networking, installation, sshd

I really want to get a fresh, network install of Ubuntu server on my old computer. No cable laying around, so is there some network installer for Ubuntu server that starts up a SSH server as soon as the thing starts so it can be remotely installed?

Answer (score 1):

try:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot

what os are you currently running?